# Appropriate use of the Tuple Class

Tags: c#, tuples

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What problem was the tuple designed to solve?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3089706/what-problem-was-the-tuple-designed-to-solve)

Could someone please show/describe an appropriate use of the System.Tuple class?

I have looked on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx) and the description there doesn't show any practical uses.

Comment: I wish stackoverflows internal searching was better...

Comment: The suggestions that appear after you enter the title seem pretty reasonable as well.

Answer (score 1):

From [the MSDN on the 2-tuple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268536.aspx):

> A tuple is a data structure that has a specific number and sequence of values. The Tuple class represents a 2-tuple, or pair, which is a tuple that has two components. A 2-tuple is similar to a KeyValuePair structure.

In the `Tuple<T1, T2>` case, It is a generalization of the `KeyValuePair<,>` data structure.

Tuples are basically generic data structures.  You can use them to avoid defining your own structure.  An example would be for returning multiple values from a function.

It is a very useful tool in function-oriented/functional programming.