# How to assign to a list of variables in one statement

Tags: c#, perl

Perl has the ability to do:

```
my ($a,$b,$c,$d) = foo();
```

where `foo` returns 4 variables, as opposed to assigning it one at a time. Is there something similar in C#?

Comment: why not make a class for it?

Comment: AFAIK no, but as @491243 said you can use class

Comment: Just interesting - when this feature can be useful?

Comment: it's just less typing for when you have a function that returns a ton of parameters, the perl notation just seems simpler

Comment: It depends on what `foo()` returns. A method can have only one return type, but that type may be an enumerable, like a `List<T>` or array. If you really need to return various variable types from one method, that method is probably doing too much.

Comment: In the Perl sample, `foo()` returns a list, the first 4 elements of which are assigned to scalar variables.

Answer (score 8):

No, basically. Options:

```
object[] values = foo();
int a = (int)values[0];
string b = (string)values[1];
// etc
```

or:

```
var result = foo();
// then access result.Something, result.SomethingElse etc
```

or:

```
int a;
string b;
float c; // using different types to show worst case
var d = foo(out a, out b, out c); // THIS WILL CONFUSE PEOPLE and is not a 
                                  // recommendation
```

Comment: @lazyberezovsky ultimately all of these things are ways of expressing multiple values outbound from a function, and assigning them to locals at the caller; the *mechanism* for that (lists, etc) is the implementation details

Comment: If you're enumerating bad options, I guess you can also include a `Tuple<int,sting,foo>` `:)`. Obviously, C# points the users to the second option - return a meaningful class.

Comment: Eric Lippert talks about tuples with a bit of inside knowledge here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3089706/what-requirement-was-the-tuple-designed-to-solve.  When I used a tuple to solve a similar problem in my current position, the guy I was working with said he wished he'd seen it before.  Apparently, the team have a long history of creating new classes just to hold values when returning data from methods.

Answer (score 2):

`Tuple` can be a useful construct for this.

```
public Tuple<int, string, double> Foo() { ... }
```

Then you can do:

```
var result = Foo();

int a = result.Item1;
string b = result.Item2;
double c = result.Item3;
```

This is a legacy of the increasing influence of functional programming styles on C#: the tuple is a fundamental construct in many functional languages, and greatly assists in their static typing.

Answer (score 1):

For functions you must return either 1 object or `void`.  But you can approach this problem several ways.

1. You can create a data structure such as a `struct` or a `class` that will contain `a,b,c,d` and return that as your function e.g. `data foo()` data will contain a,b,c,d
2. You can use the `out` keyword in the parameter of your function e.g. foo(out a, out b, out c, out d), but your variable inputs will need to be initialized.  More info here.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx(v=vs.80).aspx
3. You can also use `ref` which is similiar to out. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/14akc2c7(v=vs.80).aspx
4. Or if a,b,c,d are all the same type you can return them in the form of a collection as an `arrray` or a `list` as another member has pointed out

Also remember depending on the type that you are passing strcut vs objects that you value may be passed as a `Value` or `Reference`.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0f66670z(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Ad 4. Array, list or (preferably) an `IEnumerable`