# Using Tuples effectively to store objects

Tags: c#, asp.net, tuples

I have been working on some code and started using Tuple just to hold some data for a bit until some other functions are processed and then I use the Tuple in list to grab some information from it and send an email, for instance:

```
List<Tuple<Customer, Contact, Product>> tupleInfo = 
   new List<Tuple<Customer, Contact, Product>>();
```

Then i add the different objects to it by calling a method where I pass Customer, Contact and Product:

```
Tuple<Customer, Contact, Product> info = 
         new Tuple<Customer, Contact, Product>(myCustomer, myContact, myProduct);

info.Add(info);
```

At the end after I process all my stuff in other methods this list will endup with a maximum of 10 tuples that I then send to a method that sends an email, something like this:

```
private ActionResult SendEmails(List<Tuple<Customer, Contact, Product> list)
{
   ActionResult result = new ActionResult;
      foreach(Tuple<Customer, Contact, Product> info in list)
      {
             //Here i just grab some the information 
             //from each tuple, email, product,contact
             //contact info and customer info and send 
             //a personalized email, then do the same with the next records
      }
   return result;
}
```

My question is, how efficient is this, is it ok to use Tuples this way?, am I trading performance by using Tuples?

I am new using this so would like to know before I do it the wrong way.

Comment: No performance trade...but IMO tuples should primarily be declared and used close to each other; rarely exchanged between types in the same assembly, and almost never returned from an API consumed by others. This is especially true for types that may easily be mis-assigned to one another (e.g. Tuple<int, int, int>...no compile time safety on which member is which, and the member names are just `Item1`, `Item2`, `Item3` so it is very easy to make a mistake). For my own sanity, I usually prefer internal classes.

Comment: Thanks for the input, based on your experience or knowledge. Would it be safe to say that in the way i am using it above, it's ok?

Comment: Yes, it looks fine, since it looks like you are using it as an internal structure for convenience. You certainly won't lose any performance by using a tuple; there's [nothing special](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3089883/453277) (good or bad) about them in c#.

Comment: I think you're only sacrificing cleanliness and understandability. Those generics are really long and obscure - there's no explanation on why those 3 objects are being grouped. Something like class CustomerOrder (or at least alias) would be shorter, and more descriptive.

Comment: @MikeTrusov: I don't think he's sacrificing any. Actually, like the  OP says, this is gonna be short-lived. Declaring a custom class may bring an additional overhead. In this case, tuples is what I bet. (Mainly because, he is not gonna use this out of this context)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
" started using Tuple just to hold some data for a bit "
```

If this is the reason, then there is no harm in using Tuples.

Generally, Tuples are used to hold some data where creating a class to represent the same information may seem meaningless.

You might want to do some business-logic, for which, creating a new class is an additional overhead and irrelevant.

But also remember one thing, it is not recommended to use a function whose return type is of `TUPLE`. This does not make any sense.

Eg, A function whose return type is `EmailContent` is more clearer than a function whose return type is a tuple with some signature like `Tuple<string,int,bool,string,string>`

Personally, I would use `Tuples` as some private member or for some scenarios where they have shorter lives and not-reusable components.

So, in this case, as long as you think, "`holding some data for a bit`", its perfectly ok.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any performance drop associated with using Tuples. They are generic so it is as good as if you have written your own container class.