# Why is my query so slow?

Tags: asp.net, linq, sql-server-2008

I try to tune my query but I have no idea what I can change:

- A screenshot of both tables: http://abload.de/image.php?img=1plkyg.jpg
- The relation is: 1 UserPM (a Private Message) has 1 Sender (User, SenderID -> User.SenderID) and 1 Recipient (User, RecipientID -> User.UserID) and 1 User has X UserPMs as Recipient and X UserPMs as Sender.
- The intial load takes around 200ms, it only takes the first 20 rows and display them. After this is displayed a JavaScript PageMethod gets the `GetAllPMsAsReciepient` method and loads the rest of the data
- this `GetAllPMsAsReciepient` method takes around 4.5 to 5.0 seconds each time to run on around 250 rows

My code:

```
    public static List<UserPM> GetAllPMsAsReciepient(Guid userID)
    {
        using (RPGDataContext dc = new RPGDataContext())
        {
            DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;

            DataLoadOptions options = new DataLoadOptions();
            //options.LoadWith<UserPM>(a => a.User);
            options.LoadWith<UserPM>(a => a.User1);
            dc.LoadOptions = options;

            List<UserPM> pm = (
                      from a in dc.UserPMs 
                      where a.RecieverID == userID 
                      && !a.IsDeletedRec 
                      orderby a.Timestamp descending select a
            ).ToList();

            TimeSpan ts = DateTime.Now - dt;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ts.Seconds + "." + ts.Milliseconds);

            return pm;
        }
    }
```

I have no idea how to tune this Query, I mean 250 PMs are nothing at all, on other inboxes on other websites I got around 5000 or something and it doesn't need a single second to load...

I try to set Indexes on Timestamp to reduce the `Orderby` time but nothing happend so far.

Any ideas here?

### EDIT

I try to reproduce it on LinqPad:
Without the DataLoadOptions, in LinqPad the query needs 300ms, with DataLoadOptions around 1 Second.

So, that means:

- I could save around 60% of the time, If I can avoid to load the User-table within this query, but how?
- Why Linqpad needs only 1 second on the same connection, from the same computer, where my code is need 4.5-5.0 seconds?
- Here is the execution plan: http://abload.de/image.php?img=54rjwq.jpg
- Here is the SQL Linqpad gives me:

SELECT [t0].[PMID], [t0].[Text], [t0].[RecieverID], [t0].[SenderID], [t0].[Title], [t0].[Timestamp], [t0].[IsDeletedRec], [t0].[IsRead], [t0].[IsDeletedSender], [t0].[IsAnswered], [t1].[UserID], [t1].[Username], [t1].[Password], [t1].[Email], [t1].[RegisterDate], [t1].[LastLogin], [t1].[RegisterIP], [t1].[RefreshPing], [t1].[Admin], [t1].[IsDeleted], [t1].[DeletedFrom], [t1].[IsBanned], [t1].[BannedReason], [t1].[BannedFrom], [t1].[BannedAt], [t1].[NowPlay], [t1].[AcceptAGB], [t1].[AcceptRules], [t1].[MainProfile], [t1].[SetShowHTMLEditorInRPGPosts], [t1].[Age], [t1].[SetIsAgePublic], [t1].[City], [t1].[SetIsCityShown], [t1].[Verified], [t1].[Design], [t1].[SetRPGCountPublic], [t1].[SetLastLoginPublic], [t1].[SetRegisterDatePublic], [t1].[SetGBActive], [t1].[Gender], [t1].[IsGenderVisible], [t1].[OnlinelistHidden], [t1].[Birthday], [t1].[SetIsMenuHideable], [t1].[SetColorButtons], [t1].[SetIsAboutMePublic], [t1].[Name], [t1].[SetIsNamePublic], [t1].[ContactAnimexx], [t1].[ContactRPGLand], [t1].[ContactSkype], [t1].[ContactICQ], [t1].[ContactDeviantArt], [t1].[ContactFacebook], [t1].[ContactTwitter], [t1].[ContactTumblr], [t1].[IsContactAnimexxPublic], [t1].[IsContactRPGLandPublic], [t1].[IsContactSkypePublic], [t1].[IsContactICQPublic], [t1].[IsContactDeviantArtPublic], [t1].[IsContactFacebookPublic], [t1].[IsContactTwitterPublic], [t1].[IsContactTumblrPublic], [t1].[IsAdult], [t1].[IsShoutboxVisible], [t1].[Notification], [t1].[ShowTutorial], [t1].[MainProfilePreview], [t1].[SetSound], [t1].[EmailNotification], [t1].[UsernameOld], [t1].[UsernameChangeDate]
FROM [UserPM] AS [t0]
INNER JOIN [User] AS [t1] ON [t1].[UserID] = [t0].[RecieverID]
WHERE ([t0].[RecieverID] = @p0) AND (NOT ([t0].[IsDeletedRec] = 1))
ORDER BY [t0].[Timestamp] DESC

Comment: Most likely the `LoadWith` is what is slowing down the query, Linq probably makes one select statement per row to get the value. Try removing it and try it. You can use a tool such as LinqPad to analyse the SQL generated by linq queries.

Comment: LinqPad is a good suggestion, but I usually just go right to the DB and use the Profiler to see what the queries are doing.

Comment: without LoadWith I cant use this query because I need the Usernames

Comment: Profiler is not available for me, I use the EXPRESS Version

Comment: @Kovu Just try it to know if _that_ is the problem.

Comment: Okay, How do I insert a Loadwith-Option in LinqPad?

Comment: @Kovu you do this.LoadOptions = options;

Comment: Are you sure that RecieverID have an index? What is the generated query? `var query = from a... 
DbCommand db = dc.GetCommand(q); Console.WriteLine(dc.CommandText);` In how much time this query run?

Comment: @Magnus I tried this, but gives me an Error in LKinqPad: 
            DataLoadOptions options = new DataLoadOptions();
            options.LoadWith<UserPM>(a => a.User1);
          
this.LoadOptions = options
(from a in UserPMs where a.RecieverID == Guid.Parse("6ed39f74-5a03-4690-8af1-e4c034570406") && !a.IsDeletedRec orderby a.Timestamp descending select a).ToList()

Comment: @CyrilGandon Yes im Sure: http://abload.de/image.php?img=210jyf.jpg

Comment: @Kovu "gives me an Error" is a little vague. Can you be more specific?

Comment: @Kovu change the language dropdown to "C# Statement(s)" And add a `.Dump();` after `.ToList()`

Comment: Doesn't work at all... http://abload.de/image.php?img=4ktkcy.jpg

Comment: @Kovu I'm sure you'll figure it out. If not check the FAQ or the Linqpad Forum.

Comment: @Magnus pls see Edits!

Comment: @Kovu How did the SQL look? Was it one statement or many? Put it in Management studio and analyse the executionplan. You'll see where indexing is needed

Comment: @Kovu You have a missing index suggestions in the plan, click on that and add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

At first it seems that with the DataLoadOptions is something not okay, at second its not clever to load a table with 30 Coloumns when you only need 1.

To Solve this, I make a view which covers all nececeery fields and of course the join.

It reduces the time from 5.0 seconds to 230ms!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get rid of the LoadWith, you can select your field explicitly :

```
public static List<Tuple<UserPM, User> > GetAllPMsAsReciepient(Guid userID)
{
    using (var dataContext = new RPGDataContext())
    {
        return (
            from a in dataContext.UserPMs 
            where a.RecieverID == userID 
            && !a.IsDeletedRec 
            orderby a.Timestamp descending 
            select Tuple.Create(a, a.User1)
        ).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is a Tuple? Can you eplain it? How to use the list after this? Can I do User.Username in a Girdviewcell after this?

Comment: [What requirement was the tuple designed to solve?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3089706/what-requirement-was-the-tuple-designed-to-solve)