# What are the Advantages/Disadvantages between Tuple<X1,X2..>.Create and new Tuple<X1,X2..>

Tags: c#

Are there any guidelines for when I should use  Tuple.Create()  instead of new Tuple() ?

There must be a reason for Microsoft having 2 ways to create the same object.  Speed differences or other known advantages/disadvantaes?

Comment: Hi @shev72, check out this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3089706/what-requirement-was-the-tuple-designed-to-solve

Comment: The best option to test if there are perfomance differences is benchmarking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly in C# constructors don't do type inference. So you can't write:

```
Tuple<int, int> xxx = new Tuple(1, 2);
```

while methods do it:

```
Tuple<int, int> xxx = Tuple.Create(1, 2);
```

for using constructors you need:

```
Tuple<int, int> xxx = new Tuple<int, int>(1, 2);
```

This is more verbose.

Note that if type inference doesn't work for you (because you want a tuple of a different type than the parameters you are passing):

```
Tuple<object, object> xxx = Tuple.Create("A", "B"); // Invalid
```

then they are equivalent for verbosity:

```
Tuple<object, object> xxx = Tuple.Create<object, object>("A", "B");

Tuple<object, object> xxx = new Tuple<object, object>("A", "B");

Tuple<object, object> xxx = Tuple.Create((object)"A", (object)"B");
```

Answer (score 2):

As seen from the [source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/tuple.cs,8e2a2c5c7e686c09) `Tuple.Create(item1)` is just calling `new Tuple<T1>(item1)`. So, there is not any speed difference between them.

```
 public static Tuple<T1> Create<T1>(T1 item1) {
            return new Tuple<T1>(item1);
        }
```

So, you can create your collection with both ways:

```
Tuple<int> myTuple = Tuple.Create(1); // This one uses type inference
Tuple<int> myTuple = new Tuple<int>(1);
```

But, of course there is a reason of the existence of both constructor and generic method. *Constructors* in C# *can't support* ***type inference***. So, they have to create some ***generic method*** to ***support type inference***.
For example, this will give you compiler error:

```
Tuple<int> myTuple = new Tuple(1); // Oops, compiler error
```

So, instead of writing the above code, we can write this thanks to `Create()` method:

```
Tuple<int> myTuple = Tuple.Create(1);
```

By the way, you can read **[Eric Lippert's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3570360/1576032)** for more information, if you want to know why can't the C# constructor infer type.

Comment: The constructor is likely to run faster, because the call to `Create` might not get `inline`d.

Comment: The difference is negligible - No need for premature optimization.

Comment: thanks for the pointer to Eric Lipper's answer, very usefl and interesting read!

Answer (score 2):

No speed differences but since the `Create` is a generic method so the compiler can infer the generic argument types for you.This is not possible for the constructor.