# List<Tuple> has no setter error

Tags: c#, list, tuples

I've List Tuple with int and string in it, each time I add new position to this list, I check for the same string in already added elements. Once I see the same - the goal is to change int (to do +1). For example if we have (3, box; 1, apple; 2, PC) and we need to add "apple", so I must change existing "1, apple" to "2, apple".
But I can't do it because Item1 return error "The property has no setter".
Where my mistake?
Thanks.

```
        string[] elements = s.Split(); // Contains all elements as strings.

        List<Tuple<int, string>> elementsList = new List<Tuple<int, string>>();

        var sortItems = elementsList.OrderBy(x => x.Item1);

        for (int i = 0; i < elements.Length; i++)
        {
            foreach (var item in sortItems)
            {
                if (Equals(item.Item1, elements[i]))
                {
                    item.Item1 += 1;
                }
            }
            elementsList.Add(new Tuple<int, string>(1, elements[i]));
        }         
        return elementsList;
```

Comment: Do you have to use `List<Tuple<int, string>>`? I think your code would be a lot simpler if you went with `Dictionary<string, int>` for this purpose.

Comment: A more nice approach is `var list = elements.GroupBy(e => e).Select(g => Tuple.Create(g.Count(), g. Key)).ToList();` or similar.

Comment: Agree with @CoolBots comment, generic `Dictionary` is what you exactly need, because it is based on hash table, thus the search in dictionary will be much faster than in `List`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Tuple<T1, T2>` does not allow you to modify the values inside because it is immutable. Instead try using a `Dictionary`

```
string[] elements = s.Split(); // Contains all elements as strings.

IDictionary<string, int> elementsMap = new Dictionary<string, int>();

for (int i = 0; i < elements.Length; i++)
{
    string name = elements[i];

    if (elementsMap.ContainsKey(name))
    {
        elementsMap[name] += 1;
    }
    else
    {
        elementsMap.Add(name, 1);
    }
}
return elementsMap;
```

Or through Linq(credit to Jeppe Stig Nielsen):

```
var elementsMap = elements.GroupBy(e => e).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
```

Comment: Or with the aid of Linq, use `var elementsMap = elements.GroupBy(e => e).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen I have added that into my answer but feel free to provide it as another answer if you want the rep

Answer (score 9):

According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268536%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of `Tuple<T1,T2>`, the properties cannot be written, which basically means that tuples are immutable. It is impossible to modify its contents in-place; it is necessary to create a new tuple.

Answer (score 1):

Tuples are immutable types, so basically they are not intented to be changed and have no setter. The reasons got listed up here : [Why Tuple's items are ReadOnly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131400/why-tuples-items-are-readonly)

Either you create a new tuple (as Codor suggested) or you just create your own implementation, like shown here: [Why a Tuple, or a KeyValueItem, don't have a setter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19725158/why-a-tuple-or-a-keyvalueitem-dont-have-a-setter)

Answer (score 0):

Tuple class is immutable which means its properties do no have public setters to overwrite the underlying value.

Tuples are not meant to be used in a key-value manner, which is probably closer to what you are trying to achieve. Tuples are more suitable for pairing *- well they are could be used for more than 2 practically -* two correlated pieces of data, such as coordinates for example, or width and height.

More examples in the answers of the link below :

[Practical example where Tuple can be used in .Net 4.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745426/practical-example-where-tuple-can-be-used-in-net-4-0)

**When should you use a Dictionary ?**

Simply when you are doing lookups by a certain unique key to read/modify the an object(which could be a collection it self) corresponding to that key. a quick google around would show you tons of uses.